# iOS Adding toolbar to View -- Doesn't show up

Tags: ios

I am attempting to add a toolbar to one of my views below the UIWebView. The View loads, but the toolbar doesn't.

It is NOT in a navigation controller, it is its own view that is navigated to using a modal cross dissolve segue. Below is how I setup the view.

[image: iOS toolbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the autolayout constraints are correctly set.

On the provided screenshot I don't see any constraints in the inspector.
Select your toolbar, then reset its constraints to suggested ones.

Here is how to do it:

[image]

Comment: It appears they are set correctly. Can you provide any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, maybe try resetting them. I updated my answer with info how to do it.

Comment: That did it! What do you think could have caused the problem?

Comment: Good! :) I think the constraints were simply not there. Normally they should appear in the inspector. Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped :)